# Redirect /index.php to / without htaccess

Tags: laravel

I want redirect http://localhost/mysite/index.php to http://localhost/mysite without using .htaccess file

I've written a `Middleware` and put it in `Kernel.php` but this does not work

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(strpos($request->url(), 'index.php'))
        return Redirect::to('/', 301);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Chrome error:

> This page isn’t working
>   localhost redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: this is one of the most stupid things I have seen lately.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Why?! this is essential for me. i also redirect https to http with `if ($request->secure()) return Redirect::to($request->path(), 301);` and this work well.

Comment: you want when you access this `http://localhost/mysite/index.php` it should redirect http://localhost/mysite , so you want restrict `public/index.php` file ??

Comment: Okay, please enlighten me: why would you do it like THIS?!

Comment: The entry point of your script (aka the Laravel framework) is the `index.php`. Without a rewrite through `.htaccess` or the apache/nginx configuration, calling `/` on your server will not even call `index.php`. So this is simply not possible.

Comment: Noooo @Namoshek! Where is the fun?! :( Okay, one way he could do it. He could get the requested url by php and then echo a javascript, what replaces the url in the addressbar! :D (_yes, i hate myself for writing such thing_)

Comment: @Hamelraj Yes. I want to avoid two pages with two different addresse.

Comment: @eisbehr I want this for better seo!

Comment: Then use a rewrite condition in your `.htaccess` as suggested.

Comment: I don't mean the reason for the redirect, I mean, why do you really do such tasks with php?

Comment: @eisbehr Because I've done other things, like `https` to `http` and `www` to `non-www` by php and a middleware called `PreferredDomain`.
I wanted to have a better control and documentation on the project. Also curiosity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (strpos($request->fullUrl(), 'index.php') !== false) {
    $newUrl = str_replace('index.php', '', $request->fullUrl());
    return Redirect::to($newUrl, 301);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Routes.php or routes/web.php just define a Route with

```
Route::get('/', function() { 
    return view('viewname');
});
```

or if you want to keep it the way you used it, use

```
return redirect()->intended('viewname');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: No, i want redirect `/index.php` to `/` , now both are load a same view. i want only `/` url.

Comment: I must admit that I dont get why you want it without htaccess. Laravel's default config handles this issue clearly for you. Could you tell us what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the real requested path, not the URL. I've not tested it now, but I assume `getUrl` build it by the routes and add `index.php` by default.

So why not use php: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php'))
        return Redirect::to('/', 301);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Because you will receive the real URI, and index.php might be the only call, you could even do a check without search, what could be faster:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/index.php")
        return Redirect::to('/', 301);

    return $next($request);
}
```

But keep in mind:

`.htaccess` is by far the better and faster solution! You should totally change your rewrites to it. The code you write above will be executed on EVERY call of your side. If you do it for SEO reasons, also keep in mind the such things will increase all of your loading times!

Note: above code is not tested. ;)

Comment: Thanks. it correct but, `return Redirect::to('/', 301);`  not work. `redirected you too many times` occurs.